# Do Threads with Infinite Loops cause excessive CPU

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So this may end up being an embarrassing question, but with Java, can infinite loops in Threads cause excessive CPU usage? I'm not very knowledgeable about multithreading in Java, but my assumption had been that Java allocated equal time to all threads, regardless of whether the thread had something to do or not. So, I had implicitly assumed that infinite loops in a multithreaded environment would not burden performance, like they would in a single-threaded environment. As a result, I have a lot of code that looks like the below snippet:

```
public Thread readerThread = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      readNextMessage(); // Does nothing if there are no messages to read
    }
  }
}
readerThread.start();
```

I have recently started to notice severe performance issues in my application, and I am starting to wonder if my approach to threading is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to allocate time to a thread that has nothing to do. A thread can only be scheduled if it is ready-to-run. A thread that is blocked waiting for something to happen is not ready-to-run.

Imagine if your assumption was correct and a server has 100 threads, one for each client. Now, imagine further than most of those clients are inactive. That would mean each active client could, at most, get 1/100th of the CPU. That would be pretty awful.

Threads that consume CPU when they have nothing to do prevent the CPU from going to sleep, waste power, and degrade performance not just for other threads in the same process but for the entire system.

Answer (score -1):

If you can guarantee that the system always will have more CPUs available to run threads than the number of threads that are ready-to-run, then a "busy loop" like that is no problem.* But, when other threads have to wait for their "fair share" of CPU time, it is not helpful to have a thread that is *wasting* its own share of CPU time by continually checking whether there is any work to do, and continually finding none.

> my assumption had been that Java allocated equal time to all threads.

That is a misunderstanding. The system will try to allocate a "fair share" of CPU time to each thread *that wants it.* If a thread does not want CPU time because it is blocked waiting for I/O, blocked in an `o.wait()` call, blocked in a `Thread.sleep(...)` call, etc., then that thread drops out of the running, and its "fair share" is allocated to other threads until it "wakes up" and is again ready to run.

---

* If you ignore power consumption. A CPU executing instructions (even, instructions that do nothing useful) uses more electrical power than a CPU that is in a "wait-for-interrupt" state. A loop like that will cause the system to use more electrical power.  That could exceed power budget for a small, embedded system, or it could cause a personal computer to substantially slow down in order to prevent over-heating.  [The thermal management of PCs, especially laptops and mobile devices, is built around the assumption that the CPUs will only be used in short bursts.]

Comment: 100% disagree with your first sentence. For one thing, many modern CPUs have their clock speed limited by their temperature. So busy loops increase the temperature which reduces the clock speed, degrading performance. They can also significantly impact power consumption, which is a huge issue on high-end desktops where an idle CPU can consume 12W and a busy one 100W.